# Java fastest way to concatenate strings, integers and floats

Tags: java, string-concatenation

What is the most performant way to build strings from strings, integers and floats? currently I'm doing this and it uses a lot of cpu time.

```
String frame = this.frameTime + ":" +
    this.player.vertices[0].x + "," +
    this.player.vertices[0].y + "," +
    this.player.activeAnimId + "," +
    (int)this.player.virtualSpeed + "," +
    this.map.getCurrentTime() + 
    (this.player.frameSound == -1 ? "" : "," + this.player.frameSound) +
    (this.player.frameDecal.equals("") ? "" : "," + this.player.frameDecal) +
    ";";
```

Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: Have you tried StringBuilder?

Comment: Have you tried `String.format()` ?

Comment: @BrianHoover This uses StringBuilder.

Comment: See this post for an explanation.http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/the-optimum-method-to-concatenate.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That should already be fast - it'll use `StringBuilder` internally for concatenation. Arguably using `StringBuilder` explicitly could eliminate the concatenation of empty strings, but it's not likely to make a big difference.

How often are you doing this, anyway? It must be pretty often, for it to be a bottleneck... do you really *need* to do it that often?

EDIT: For those who are saying "Use StringBuilder, it'll be faster" - consider this code:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;
        int z = 30;
        String foo = x + "," + y + "," + z + ";";
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

Compile that, then use `javap -c` to see what the compiler generates...

Comment: That was my thought as well - although I'm not clear in what cases this will happen. Is it when you use the + operator in a loop that the compiler won't convert?

Comment: you could initialize the builder with a capacity you know is enough (but such a short string this won't gain much). also why do you need this, logging?

Comment: @zolex: Do you *really* need to do this on every frame? Really? Whose benefit is this for?

Comment: @JavaKungFu: It's not necessarily in a loop. It's when you use the result of a string concatenation expression, basically - so if you did `String foo = x + ","; foo = foo + z; foo = foo + ",";` etc *that* would be wasteful.

Comment: @zolex Does that mean you have time between frames? Can you do this in a background thread?

Comment: i already have a thread which writes the strings into a file. would it be better to pass the thread the single values and also let the thread build the string?

Comment: @zolex: In that case, it might be better not to build an intermediate string at all, but simply to write the values directly into the `Writer`, rather than concatenating them before you write them.

Comment: @zolex: If you're writing these to a file, I'd expect that to be somewhat more of a problem than the string concatenation itself. But yes, if you're currently doing this on a critical thread, passing that processing to a different thread could be useful. Do you really need it in *string* format in your log file anyway?

Comment: @JonSkeet, how else could i write it to a file to be able to read it again?

Comment: currently I write the files like this https://gist.github.com/2423077 and read them like this https://gist.github.com/2423082. Is it possible to not write string into the file but like binary content and read it again?

Comment: @zolex: Eek, you're calling `getBytes()` using the default encoding. Please don't do that. Use an `OutputStreamWriter` instead if you *really* need a string representation. But why not use `DataOutputStream` to write just the binary data you want to record? No string conversion required.

Comment: @JonSkeet, seems to work fine, but now I have the problem that when i read the file there seem to be spaces between each char. Do i also now have to read the file differently? this is the new writer https://gist.github.com/2423077

Comment: @zolex: Why are you writing all those characters? You should *only* write the data you need in each entry. When you read the file, you should be reading it back with `DataInputStream` in the same format. It's not a text file any more - it's an efficient representation of just the data you need.

Comment: @JonSkeet i'm writing them to be able to separate the values when reading, or how would one do it properly?

Comment: @zolex: You know the length of each value, because it's guaranteed in `DataOutput`. Just call `readFloat`, `readInt` etc.

Comment: @JonSkeet, hm first thing i put is `writeChars()` when i do `readUTF()` it still gets the string with spaces between each char and addiionally many specialchars behind...

Comment: ic, i should use `writeUTF()` lets try... ^^

Comment: @zolex: Use `writeUTF` instead then - that's the matching call for `readUTF`.

Comment: @zolex: It sounds like this is now a *very* different question - I suggest you post a new question, with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `StringBuilder`.

```
String string = new StringBuilder("abcd").append(23).append(false).append("xyz").toString();
```

Comment: Why do you believe that would be faster, out of interest?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a `StringBuilder`.

(However, most Java compilers worth their salt will automatically optimize the code you've listed to use `StringBuilder` behind the scenes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to go really fast you can try my library which allows you to log messages in under a micro-second without creating any garbage. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

(As I say, it likely to be over the top for what you want)

Answer (score -1):

concat3 method as below works fastest for me, performance for concat1 is jvm implementation/optimization dependent, it may perform better in other version of JVM but on my windows machine and remote linux red hat machine i tested on shows concat3 works the fastest ..

```
public class StringConcat {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int run = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
    long startTime, total = 0;

    final String a = "aafswerg";
    final String b = "assdfsaf";
    final String c = "aasfasfsaf";
    final String d = "afafafdaa";
    final String e = "afdassadf";

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    concat1(run, a, b, c, d, e);
    total = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(total);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    concat2(run, a, b, c, d, e);
    total = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(total);

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    concat3(run, a, b, c, d, e);
    total = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(total);
}

private static void concat3(int run, String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < run; i++) {
        String str = new StringBuilder(a.length() + b.length() + c.length() + d.length() + e.length()).append(a)
                .append(b).append(c).append(d).append(e).toString();
    }
}

private static void concat2(int run, String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < run; i++) {
        String str = new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).append(d).append(e).toString();
    }
}

private static void concat1(int run, String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < run; i++) {
        String str = a + b + c + d + e;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this program do it in practice to show which apprach is the fastest. and can be tested while running. please let me know why downvotes.